# Add html td tag items during a for loop to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some html I want to put into one large dictionary.

UPDATE:
The raw html (which is in the "rows" variable) is as follows:

```
[<tr>
<td class="top">
<span class="bold">Districts</span>
</td>
<td class="left top">
<span class="bold">Symbol</span>
</td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Agricultural Districts

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Agriculture

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              A

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Residential Districts

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Single-family Residential

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              R-1

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Planned Multiple Residential

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              PRD

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Planned Unit Development

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              PUD

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Mobile/ Modular Home

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Subdivision /Planned Unit

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Development

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              MHS/PUD

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Mobile Home Park Planned

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Development

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              MHP

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Commercial Districts

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Commercial Planned Development

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              CPD

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Central Business District

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              CB

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Resort

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              RES

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Industrial Districts

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               General Industry

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              M

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Industrial/Research Park

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              M-RP

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Coastal Dependent Industry

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              M-CD

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                              Other Districts

                           </td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top"></td>
<td class="top"></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Recreation

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              REC

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Public Utility

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              UT

                           </td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td class="top">
                               Community Facility

                           </td>
<td class="top">
                              CF

                           </td>
</tr>]
```

I have used beautiful soup to get the 'td' entries. Then I have stripped them down to just the text (even if it is blank) and now I would like to create a dictionary from them.

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
find_table = soup.find('table')
rows = find_table.find_all('tr')

districts_table = {}
for i in rows:
    table_data = i.find_all('td')
    results = [(j.text.replace(u'\u2002','').replace(u'\n','')).strip() for j in table_data]
    print(results)
```

Which print as shown below. But I would like to create a dictionary of these instead even if the value is empty (replace with 'None')

```
['Districts', 'Symbol']
['', '']
['Agricultural Districts', '']
['', '']
['Agriculture', 'A']
['', '']
['Residential Districts', '']
['', '']
['Single-family Residential', 'R-1']
['Planned Multiple Residential', 'PRD']
['Planned Unit Development', 'PUD']
['Mobile/ Modular Home', '']
['Subdivision /Planned Unit', '']
['Development', 'MHS/PUD']
['Mobile Home Park Planned', '']
['Development', 'MHP']
['', '']
['Commercial Districts', '']
['', '']
['Commercial Planned Development', 'CPD']
['Central Business District', 'CB']
['', '']
['Industrial Districts', '']
['', '']
['General Industry', 'M']
['Industrial/Research Park', 'M-RP']
['Coastal Dependent Industry', 'M-CD']
['', '']
['Other Districts', '']
['', '']
['Public Utility', 'UT']
['Community Facility', 'CF']
```

Instead of this I want something like:

```
{'Districts': 'Symbol',
'None': 'None',
'Agricultural Districts': 'None',
'None': 'None',
'None': 'None',
'Agriculture': 'A',
etc..}
```

How would I go about this?
I have tried dictionary comprehension as below

```
    results = {(j.text.replace(u'\u2002','').replace(u'\n','')).strip():(j.text.replace(u'\u2002','').replace(u'\n','')).strip() for j in table_data}
```

But this repeats each entry and only the last

```
{'Community Facility': 'Community Facility', 'CF': 'CF'}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What the `rows` looks like? Please provide a [Minimal  Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide the structure of ```<td>``` or else the URL. We cannot help you without any of these.

Comment: Updated @ThePyGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to populate `districts_table` as a list of dicts:

```
districts_table = []

for i in rows:
    table_data = i.find_all('td')
    results = [(j.text.replace(u'\u2002','').replace(u'\n','')).strip() for j in table_data]
    districts_table.append({'Community Facility': results[0] if results[0] else None, 'CF': results[1] if results[1] else None})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RJ I worked it out with your advice

```
    districts_table.update({results[0] if results[0] else None: results[1] if results[1] else None})
```

Gets me the below

```
{'Districts': 'Symbol', None: None, 'Agricultural Districts': None, 'Agriculture': 'A', 'Residential Districts': None, 'Single-family Residential': 'R-1', 'Planned Multiple Residential': 'PRD', 'Planned Unit Development': 'PUD', 'Mobile/ Modular Home': None, 'Subdivision /Planned Unit': None, 'Development': 'MHP', 'Mobile Home Park Planned': None, 'Commercial Districts': None, 'Commercial Planned Development': 'CPD', 'Central Business District': 'CB', 'Resort': 'RES', 'Industrial Districts': None, 'General Industry': 'M', 'Industrial/Research Park': 'M-RP', 'Coastal Dependent Industry': 'M-CD', 'Other Districts': None, 'Recreation': 'REC', 'Public Utility': 'UT', 'Community Facility': 'CF'}
```

Thanks everyone!